# A theorem of symmetric positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following true?

> Let $g=(g_{ij})\in M(n,\Bbb R)$ be a symmetric positive-definite matrix and let $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\Bbb R^n$ be any vector. Then,
>   $$v^Tgv=1\implies (v\cdot a)^2\leq a^Tg^{-1}a,$$
>   or in other words,
>   $$g_{ij}v^iv^j=1\implies v^iv^ja_ia_j\le g^{ij}a_ia_j,$$
>   (with Einstein summation).

I was trying to prove that the gradient
$$grad(f)=g_{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}$$
on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is the vector that has the greatest directional derivatives among all $v\in T_pM$ such that $|v|_g=1$ and came up with this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true.  We note that, applying the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to the inner product induced by $g$, we have
$$
v^Tgv = 1 \implies |v^Tgx|^2 \leq x^Tgx
$$
For any $x \in \Bbb R^n$. Now, let $x = g^{-1}a$, and we have
$$
v^Tgv = 1 \implies |v^Ta|^2 \leq a^Tg^{-1}a
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $v$ with $Rv$ and $a$ with $R^{-1}a$, where $R$ is the symmetric root of $g$ and the claim reduces to Cauchy-Schwarz on $\mathbb R^n$.